# css div positioning for header content footer

Tags: css, html, positioning

How should i style my content div and footer div so that:
if my content is long then the content div will expend longer.
the footer div will stick to the bottom of the div content.

```
<body>
<div id=master>
<div id=header>
<div id=content>
<div id=footer></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The following shows my css, but it doesn't work as how i want it to be.

```
body {
background-color: #03C;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
height: 100%;
}

#master {
width: 920px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: auto;
}

#header {
position:absolute;
width:920px;
height:100px;
z-index:1;
top: 25px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #000099;
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-style: normal;
line-height: normal;
font-weight: bolder;
font-variant: normal;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
}

#content {
position:absolute;
width:920px;
height:900px;
z-index:2;
left: 0px;
top: 100px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 20px;
/* [disabled]padding-left: 130px; */
padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

#footer {
position:absolute;
width:920px;
height:30px;
z-index:3;
background-color: #000099;
bottom: 0px;
color: #FFF;
left: 0px;
top: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need CSS to achieve what you're asking, you've described the normal flow of block elements.

This will do what you want:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    Content here.
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Main things you need to look at are that I haven't nested the `footer` within the `content` and I haven't got any elements positioned `absolute`, which is causing your problem.

Your CSS can be greatly simplified to this:

```css
div#header,
div#content,
div#footer
{
    width: 920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#header
{
    height: 100px;
    background: #009;
}

div#content
{
    background: #FFF;
}

div#footer
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #009;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But all the DIVs now are all left aligned. how to make them to  center?

Comment: @Newbie If you're still holding all of these items within the `master` container that you have above, you'll need to make that `920px` wide and give it `margin: auto` as well.

Comment: I have removed the master container. Now everything works as i want. Thanks for your help ;)